# save an attribute value to a variable

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I need to save an attribute value to a variable to be sent to a later object to verify a picture I upload which gets a unique src id is accessible using the src attribute I obtain. Later a search through a list of pictures will be done to find that particular uploaded picture.

```js
getPictureSrc: function() {
    var el = $('img');
    var uniqueId = el.getAttribute('src');
    return uniqueId;
  },
  findPicture: function() {
    browser.get('a different webpage then the upload page');
    var findPic = getPictureSrc();
    var allPics = $$('img');
    helper.expectedConditions.isVisible(allPics.$(findPics));
  },
```

However when I run this code, I do a `console.log()` and it throws back the list of available commands. Not the source.  However if I do an expect against some random value the src does show.  So I guess there are two questions, how do I print an attribute value to console and how do I pass an attribute value from object to object.  Thank you.

Comment: you should be aware that usually the double dollar ($$) means the variable it's supposed to be private in angular and therefore not to be used

Comment: @Gianmarco this is the protractor syntax shortcut for `element.all(by.css("smth"))` - it has nothing to do with angular itself. Thanks.

Comment: ok sorry, never used protractor, is on my radar at the moment ;)

Answer (score 2):

> However when I run this code, I do a console.log() and it throws back the list of available commands.

`getPictureSrc()` *returns a promise*. A promise is what you see printed on the console. If you need the actual value, resolve the promise explicitly:

```
getPictureSrc().then(function (src) {
    console.log(src);
});
```

> However if I do an expect against some random value the src does show.

This is the magic of the `expect()` - it is patched (by `jasminewd` package) to implicitly resolve promises before making an expectation. Having `expect()` accepting promises is quite convenient.

Comment: As always very helpful!! I will give that a try in a few minutes!